# Neural Network with backpropogation not converging

Tags: java, backpropagation, neural-network

Basically I'm trying to implement `backpropogation` in a network. I know the backpropogation algorithm is hard coded, but I'm trying to make it functional first.

It works for one set of inputs and outputs but beyond one training set the network converges on one solution while the other output converges on 0.5.

I.e the output for one trial is:
`[0.9969527919933012, 0.003043774988797313]`

`[0.5000438200377985, 0.49995612243030635]`

`Network.java`

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> weights;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> nodes;

private final double LEARNING_RATE = -0.25;
private final double DEFAULT_NODE_VALUE = 0.0;

private double momentum = 1.0;

public Network() {
    weights = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>>();
    nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
}

/**
 * This method is used to add a layer with {@link n} nodes to the network.
 * @param n number of nodes for the layer
 */
public void addLayer(int n) {
    nodes.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).add(DEFAULT_NODE_VALUE);
}

/**
 * This method generates the weights used to link layers together.
 */
public void createWeights() {
    // there are only weights between layers, so we have one less weight layer than node layer
    for (int i = 0;i < nodes.size()-1;i++) {
        weights.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>());

        // for each node above the weight
        for (int j = 0;j < nodes.get(i).size();j++) {
            weights.get(i).add(new ArrayList<Double>());

            // for each node below the weight
            for (int k = 0;k < nodes.get(i+1).size();k++)
                weights.get(i).get(j).add(Math.random()*2-1);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Utilizes the differentiated sigmoid function to change weights in the network
 * @param out   The desired output pattern for the network
 */
private void propogateBackward(double[] out) {
    /*
     * Error calculation using squared error formula and the sigmoid derivative
     * 
     * Output Node : dk = Ok(1-Ok)(Ok-Tk)
     * Hidden Node : dj = Oj(1-Oj)SummationkEK(dkWjk)
     * 
     * k is an output node
     * j is a hidden node
     * 
     * dw = LEARNING_RATE*d*outputOfpreviousLayer(not weighted)
     * W = dW + W
     */

    // update the last layer of weights first because it is a special case

    double dkW = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i < nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).size();i++) {

        double outputK = nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).get(i);
        double deltaK = outputK*(1-outputK)*(outputK-out[i]);

        for (int j = 0;j < nodes.get(nodes.size()-2).size();j++) {
            weights.get(1).get(j).set(i, weights.get(1).get(j).get(i) + LEARNING_RATE*deltaK*nodes.get(nodes.size()-2).get(j) );
            dkW += deltaK*weights.get(1).get(j).get(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < nodes.get(nodes.size()-2).size();i++) {

        //Hidden Node : dj = Oj(1-Oj)SummationkEK(dkWjk)
        double outputJ = nodes.get(1).get(i);
        double deltaJ = outputJ*(1-outputJ)*dkW*LEARNING_RATE;

        for (int j = 0;j < nodes.get(0).size();j++) {
            weights.get(0).get(j).set(i, weights.get(0).get(j).get(i) + deltaJ*nodes.get(0).get(j) );
        }


    }

}

/**
 * Propogates an array of input values through the network
 * @param in    an array of inputs
 */
private void propogateForward(double[] in) {
    // pass the weights to the input layer
    for (int i = 0;i < in.length;i++)
        nodes.get(0).set(i, in[i]);

    // propagate through the rest of the network
    // for each layer after the first layer
    for (int i = 1;i < nodes.size();i++)

        // for each node in the layer
        for (int j = 0;j < nodes.get(i).size();j++) {

            // for each node in the previous layer
            for (int k = 0;k < nodes.get(i-1).size();k++)

                // add to the node the weighted output from k to j
                nodes.get(i).set(j, nodes.get(i).get(j)+weightedNode(i-1, k, j));

            // once the node has received all of its inputs we can apply the activation function
            nodes.get(i).set(j, activation(nodes.get(i).get(j)));

        }   
}

/**
 * This method returns the activation value of an input
 * @param   in the total input of a node
 * @return  the sigmoid function at the input
 */
private double activation(double in) {
    return 1/(1+Math.pow(Math.E,-in));
}

/**
 * Weighted output for a node.
 * @param layer the layer which the transmitting node is on
 * @param node  the index of the transmitting node
 * @param previousNode  the index of the receiving node
 * @return  the output of the transmitting node times the weight between the two nodes
 */
private double weightedNode(int layer, int node, int nextNode) {
    return nodes.get(layer).get(node)*weights.get(layer).get(node).get(nextNode);
}

/**
 * This method resets all of the nodes to their default value
 */
private void resetNodes() {
    for (int i = 0;i < nodes.size();i++)
        for (int j = 0;j < nodes.get(i).size();j++)
            nodes.get(i).set(j, DEFAULT_NODE_VALUE);
}

/**
 * Teach the network correct responses for certain input values.
 * @param in    an array of input values
 * @param out   an array of desired output values
 * @param n     number of iterations to perform
 */
public void train(double[] in, double[] out, int n) {
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        propogateForward(in);
        propogateBackward(out);
        resetNodes();
    }
}

public void getResult(double[] in) {
    propogateForward(in);
    System.out.println(nodes.get(2));
    resetNodes();
}
```

`SnapSolve.java`

```
public SnapSolve() {

    Network net = new Network();
    net.addLayer(2);
    net.addLayer(4);
    net.addLayer(2);
    net.createWeights();

    double[] l = {0, 1};
    double[] p = {1, 0};

    double[] n = {1, 0};
    double[] r = {0, 1};

    for(int i = 0;i < 100000;i++) {
        net.train(l, p, 1);
        net.train(n, r, 1);
    }

    net.getResult(l);
    net.getResult(n);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SnapSolve();
}
```

Comment: Two notes: 1. please try to word your questions so that it requires less domain-specific knowledge to understand, and phrase it so that someone with programming knowledge, but lacking the special domain would understand it for the first reading, you'll get help much faster 2. the `SnapSolve` constructor is misused... Why do zou need that? just put that into the main() method... (Very nicely formatted first question, I must say, keep that up!)

Comment: Try choosing the data randomly for training, not in the same order each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Suggestions

- The initial weights you're using in your network are pretty large. Typically you want to initialize weights in a sigmoid-activation neural network proportionally to the inverse of the square root of the fan-in of the unit. So, for units in layer i of the network, choose initial weights between positive and negative n^{-1/2}, where n is the number of units in layer i-1. (See http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/precond.html for more information.)
- The learning rate parameter that you seem to be using is also fairly large, which can cause your network to "bounce around" during training. I'd experiment with different values for this, on a log scale: 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01, 0.005, ... until you find one that appears to work better.
- You're really only training on two examples (though the network you're using should be able to model these two points easily). You can increase the diversity of your training dataset by adding noise to the existing inputs and expecting the network to produce the correct output. I've found that this helps sometimes when using a squared-error loss (like you're using) and trying to learn a binary boolean operator like XOR, since there are very few input-output pairs in the true function domain to train with.

#### Monitoring

Also, I'd like to make a general suggestion that might help in your approach to problems like this: add a little bit of code that will allow you to monitor the current error of the network when given a known input-output pair (or entire "validation" dataset).

If you can monitor the error of the network during training, it will help you see more clearly when the network is converging -- the error should decrease steadily as you train the network. If it bounces all around, you'll know that you're either using too large a learning rate or need to otherwise adapt your training dataset. If the error increases, something is wrong with your gradient computations.

Comment: I would vote you up but I don't have enough reputation yet! Your suggestions got me on the right track and the link you posted solidified my understanding a little more. My outputs are right were I'd like them, thanks for the help.

Comment: Great ! I think you can always accept the answer, if you found that it suitably answered your question -- just click on the check mark under the voting buttons.